# Material UI (v1.0) : Force a new line for a TextField

Tags: material-ui

What is the best way to force a new line in a list of TextFields.

For example from the [examples](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/text-fields/)  :

[image]

Comment: Not really clear your question. What do you want to do ? Add new Textfield or add new line in your Textfield ?

Comment: hi, add a new line after the first field

Comment: With `<div>` tag like this to do your second screen : 

                <div> <TextField />  </div>
                <div>
                    <TextField />
                    <TextField />
                </div>
<div> <TextField />  </div>

Comment: Can you make it an answer please @LaPoule?

Comment: ok @joels I'll do that

Comment: adding div does not work

Answer (score 4):

With `<div>` tag like this to do your second screen

```
<div><TextField/></div>
<div><TextField/><TextField/></div>
<div><TextField/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please import Grid from mui core like this:

```
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
```

now inside your component you should wrap your items inside `Grid` like this:

```
<Grid
  container
  direction="column"
  justifyContent="center"
  alignItems="center"
>
   <TextField />
   ....
</Grid>
```